# Localization data missing from Youtube data API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am currently using the Youtube data API trying to get localised subtitle data and while this works for most videos it isn't working for this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0FhXknxYj4. The video has Danish subtitles but when you use the API or API demo (setting part as localization) here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list there is no subtitle data.

Example response for working video:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/zgsYC3imu6Fd_dFVfGFSGv4yads\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/3xUeT9GTC6osUJsmbTXqY1OMfsc\"",
   "id": "S3YnYrcD1sQ",
   "localizations": {
    "da": {
     "title": "København: Europas første markedsplads for byrelaterede data - Hitachi",
     "description": "Hitachi skaber en datamarkedsplads for Danmarks hovedstad, der skal styrke innovationen.\n\nhttp://www.hitachi.eu/en/case_studies/city-data-exchange"
    },
    "en": {
     "title": "Copenhagen: Europe's first city data exchange - Hitachi",
     "description": "Hitachi is creating a data marketplace for Denmark's capital, to help power innovation.\n\nhttp://www.hitachi.eu/en/case_studies/city-data-exchange"
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Example response for broken video (Q0FhXknxYj4):

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/UrnoPP0xkF1sGZFODge_h_h01KU\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/Y82zqHiktkqS1qFvTSCoJ5BEJas\"",
   "id": "Q0FhXknxYj4"
  }
 ]
}
```

Does anyone know why the API might not pull in the localisation data even though the subtitles are there?

Many thanks,

Emily

Comment: The problem may not have nothing to do with Youtube API itself but with the people who uploaded the video. [Localizing video metadata](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6300772?hl=en) requires process and setup. It maybe that those who uploaded it skipped something. You can read more on the link.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example does not contain any subtitle data either. It only contains localizations of the video title and description.

You need to be using [captions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions), not `list`, to list subtitle details.